# How can I allow fb users to submit their details once within my app & store this information for any other reoccuring visit?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I need to give users the opportunity to submit their details only once and then continue their experience with my app and not be asked to submit again and wanted to know the best way to go about this. how can their facebook ID be stored in the database giving them a different experience to those users who haven't submitted yet ?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just accept any user details when they sign up, store them in a database row with their username and (hopefully hashed) password and make them available when they sign in.

Facebook API has great documentation on how authentication works.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Also, here's a pretty decent tut on user authentication and session tracking with PHP, which shows you how to store user data and retrieve it based on a logged in user.

http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/

Cheers